# Is there a formula to produce the image of a straight line under an arbitrary angle rotation in coordinate geometry?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, analytic-geometry, rotations

Given a line *y = ax+b* , I observe (with the graphing calculator) a rotation when the slope *a* is changed or when x is substituted for y and vice-versa.

But this does not allow me to produce any rotation I want.

Is there a formula that allows to produce any rotation desired, with any angle whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate about the origin, apply the rotation matrix
$$ R(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\-\sin\theta &\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$
to the vector $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$. We get
$$-x\sin\theta +y\cos\theta =a (x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta) + b.$$
Rearranging, this gives
$$y(\cos\theta-a\sin\theta)=x(a\cos\theta+\sin\theta)+b,$$
or
$$y = \frac{a \cos\theta+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta-a\sin\theta}x+\frac{b}{\cos\theta-a\sin\theta}.$$
Note that setting $\theta=0$ recovers the original equation.

The formula only works when $\cos\theta-a\sin\theta\neq 0$, but the case when this is equal to zero corresponds exactly to when the line is rotated to be vertical and hence cannot be put in the form $y=a'x+b'$.